# Why button function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any opinions on this? When the user presses the button the initially hidden div must show itself on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>
        div {
        display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        function show() {
                $("div").toggle();
        }
    </script>

    </head>


    <body>
    <p>Animals are cute!</p>
    <div><p>Some text gonna blow up some pixels!</p></div>
    <button onclick="show()">Click</button>

    </body>

    </html>
```

The exactly written error in the Console:

```
ReferenceError: show is not defined[Learn More
```

Comment: You **have to** define/put the script at the bottom of page.

Comment: put the function in another script tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the inline script into its own tag. You can't use an external script and inline script in the same tag.

So:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function show() {
    $("div").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show() {
    $(".any-text").toggle();
}
```

```css
.any-text {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
          <p>Animals are cute!</p>
          <div class="any-text"><p>Some text gonna blow up some pixels!</p></div>
          <button onclick="show()">Click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```